# jQuery, IE10, Ajax html function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, internet-explorer-10

I'm stumped on this one and have looked everywhere for help.  I am using a jquery ajax call to another page that goes to my server to return an html fragment containing  rows of a table and inserting the rows into a tbody element in my calling page for display.  This works great everywhere except IE10 (not surprising).  What seems to be happening is under IE10 with the html() function, I am only getting the data content for the rows and not the full html.

Here is my ajax call:

```
  $.ajax(
  {
     async: false,
     url: "../scripts/getdata.jsp",
     type: "POST",
     datatype: "html",
     data:
     {
     parm1: $("#parm1").val()
     },
       success: function (response, status, xhr)
     {
        var retCode = $(response).find("#retCode").text();
        if (retCode== "-1")
        {
           top.location.href="../scripts/error.jsp";
        }
        else
        {
           var myData = $(response).find("#myList").html();
           alert (myData);
           $("#myTable #myTableBody").empty().html(myData);
           ....
```

My response being returned from post is fine.  In all browsers except IE10, the data my alert is something like:

```
 `<tr><td><input id=xxxx type=checkbox></td><td>my name</td></tr>`
```

which is what I want.  However, in IE10, I get the following from the html() function:

```
 `<INPUT id=xxxx type=checkbox>myname`
```

Sorry for the formatting above, but in IE10 I don't get any of the html structure for the TR/TD tags.

Is there a different way to do this to make it work in IE10 also, while still working in all the other browsers.  IE10 is so frustrating...

I should point out I am using jquery 1.11.0.

Many thanks.

Comment: have you defined dataType to be returned in jQuery? And how are you returning the object response ($(response))?

Comment: here is the full ajax call:        $.ajax(
      {
         async: false,
         url: "../script/getdata.jsp",
         type: "POST",
         datatype: "html",
         data:
         {
      parm1: $("#parm1").val()
         },
         success: function (response, status, xhr)
         {
            var retCode = $(response).find("#retCode").text();
            if (retCode== "-1")
            {
               top.location.href="../script/error.jsp";
            }
            else
            {
            alert (response);
               var myData= $(response).find("#myList").html();

Comment: Please update your question with the ajax call - so it's easy to read/understand.

Comment: var myData = $(response).find("#myList").html(); could be replaced with var myData = $("#myList").html(); if the html is written correctly because #myList should be an unique element.

Comment: I will try that and meanwhile updated my original question.

Comment: I got an undefined when doing an alert of myData after the change

Comment: It looks like IE is trying to clean up your invalid HTML.  Make sure your `<tr>` is inside of a `<table>`.  Also, you need to quote the attributes on your `<input>` tag.

Comment: perhaps ie10 is pickier.  the <table><tbody> is actually in the calling page and what is returned are the tr/td tags and they are just plugged into the tbody in the calling page, so yes what is in the returned html fragment is no <table>.  frustrating because it works everywhere else w/o any issues.  I did it this way so the table headers would be static in the calling page and not have to be returned in the ajax call.    attribute are actually quoted, just didnt put that in the text here.

Comment: Rocket,  I got it to work by doing what you suggested and just adding a dummy <table> on the return and now it works on IE10, but now doesn't work in lower browsers.  is there jquery command to determine what browser is running, so I can extract the right piece depending on the browser ?

Comment: FYI I can reproduce this in Chrome 35 using a static response HTML of `<div><div id="myList"><tr><td><input id=xxxx type=checkbox></td><td>my name</td></tr></div></div>`.

However using a more valid response HTML of `<table><tbody id="myList"><tr><td><input id=xxxx type=checkbox></td><td>my name</td></tr></tbody></table>` returns correctly.

Comment: yes, I did that and it works in IE10, but now does not work in IE8, 9 or IE10 compatability view (these are required).  Any idea how I can get it to work in both.

Comment: Can you show us the actual html that is returned? My guess is that it is somehow invalid. You say it works in IE10, but it really doesn't if you have to have compability mode on.